# Visual C++ GetGlyphOutline and Chinese characters

Tags: visual-c++, vector, unicode, character-encoding, character

I have a problem with `GetGlyphOutlineW` function and i can't solve it. I have declared `LOGFONT` structure and all of input characters are stored in variable of type `WCHAR* (UNICODE)`. When I'am try to draw that characters using `DrawText`, all of glyphs are properly rednered but when I'am using points returned from `GetGlyphOutline/GetGlyphOutlineW` - Asian characters are displayed as rectangles. Only way to using properly those characters is using `SHIFTJIS_CHARSET` but `WCHAR`* is a dynamic array of characters and it is possible there may be mixed characters from diffrents charsets. Could anybody help me?
Regrades W.Czech

Comment: Are you able to add a code example?

Comment: @MartinEvans :It's a little difficult becouse i try to write rtf decoding dll an my code  associated with glyph generating is very divided into part and placed in diffrent places. All funcions i use are "W" Functions (like `GetGlyphOutlineW`) so there shouldn't be any problems with unicode characters. I dont know why i must use `CHARSET` if i want to use `UNICODE` :( If I use one of charsets i can't use whole characters array and I must stay in one characterset boundaries.